# Creating a "Modeless" window using tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I am a python/tkinter newbie and am struggling to have a "modeless window" appear in front of my root canvas whilst some work is done and then to close it programatically.

Have been days trying to understand how to do this.  In the RAD tool that I use it is 1 line of code so I am definitely out of my depth!

```
from tkinter import * 
from functools import partial
import time

# creating tkinter window 
root = Tk() 
root.overrideredirect(True)

#Define variables

HomeDir = "/temp/" #Home Directory for images etc

# Creating a photoimage object to use on main canvas button 

photo1 = PhotoImage(file = HomeDir + "B1.gif") 

#Create and populate the canvas

w = Canvas(root, width=1024, height=680, highlightthickness=0)
BackgroundImage = PhotoImage(file = HomeDir + "BackGroundImage.gif")
BackgroundCreated = w.create_image((0,0), image=BackgroundImage, anchor=NW)
TopMsg = w.create_text((320, 20), text="TEST", font="MSGothic 30 bold", anchor=NW)
w.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "no")

#Define button actions

def ButtonAction(BN):
    print("Button " + str(BN)) # For debug purposes

    #At this point I want a modeless "Window" to pop up with an image and 
    #some text on it such as "Button X Clicked"
    #and then after a few seconds I want the "Window" to close automatically


# Adding widgets to the root window 

B1 = Button(root, image = photo1, command=partial(ButtonAction,1)).place(x=100,y=300) 


mainloop()
```

From the code, I am trying to make the def ButtonAction(BN): do the following:

pop up a smaller "Modeless window" in front of the root canvas so that I can show something like "Please wait..." and an image that populates the whole window.

Do some work, so have tried to emulate this using sleep to pause the operation for a bit.

Kill off the modeless window and revert back to the main canvas again.

I won't post any of my efforts to do this as I think I am getting things totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is create an instance of `Toplevel`, and then put any widgets you want in it. `Toplevel` windows are modeless by default.

To kill it off after a period of time you can use `after`. It would look something like this:

```
def ButtonAction(BN):
    top = Toplevel(root)
    label = Label(top, text="Button {} clicked".format(BN))
    label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

    top.after(5000, top.destroy)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works just as it should and is simpler than anything I tried